# Foreground-service, Alarm-manager, notificationsnow showing

Tags: java, android, push-notification, foreground-service

I have some trouble with foreground service, alarmManager and notifications.

Basicly I'm trying to do service which gives notification every morning. I'm trying to do this with foregroundService and cpuWakeLock but some reason I'm still having trouble to get this notification launch every morning. In emulator everything works fine.

Main reason to use foreground-service is that without it i havent get working that alarms keep firing when app is closed.

I'm little bit **desperate**.

Here is my Code (cleaned version)

```
public class MentorService_cleaned extends Service {
NotificationManager notificationManager;

private PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakeLock = null;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    super.onCreate();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pficon)
            .setContentTitle("xxx")
            .setContentText("xxx")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    startForeground(1337, notification);


    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int alarmHour = 7;
    int alarmMinute = 0;

    alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMinute);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if (alarmStartTime.before(now)) { //if it's after 7:00 move to next day
        alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    Intent _Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, _Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);


    // test pushNotification
    pushNotification();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    try {
        if ((cpuWakeLock == null) || cpuWakeLock.isHeld() == false) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "ShakeEventService onCreate Tag");
            cpuWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (this.cpuWakeLock.isHeld())
        this.cpuWakeLock.release();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public void pushNotification(){

    try {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificBuilder.setContentTitle("xxx");
        //notificBuilder.setContentText(nextCard.caption);
        //notificBuilder.setTicker(nextCard.caption);

        notificBuilder.setContentText("xxx");
        notificBuilder.setTicker("xxx");

        notificBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.book);
        notificBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        tStackBuilder.addParentStack(Card.class);
        tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService((Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));

        if (PFContents.profile.Notification) {
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificBuilder.build());
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}}
```

AlertReceicer-class

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {

    Intent in = new Intent(ctxt, MentorService.class);
    in.putExtra("fromMain", "false");
    ctxt.startService(in);
}
```

}

And here my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<service
            android:name=".MentorService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=".myprocess"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need a service to deliver notification. It will drain your battery.
- Use Alarm Manager to perform your task you can set a alarm periodically after 24 hr.
- when one alarm triggers - generate next one.

Other than this You can try GCMNetworkManager, which is extension on Alarmmanager.

AlarManager code:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

Here Your **AlarmReceiver.class (i.e which extends BroadcastReciever)** will trigger where yo can do your things:
- create your notification.
- modify the next alarm if required.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will test this and let you know.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand logic of that setRepeating. Is this going to call this AlarmReceiver.class every 20 minuts in this example or just time of 8:30?

Comment: Yes instead of 20 min you can set it to 24 hr.

-- calendar.getTimeInMillis() is your morning time millies

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. Just to be clear. Why using alarmMgr.setRepeating, why not just alarmMagr.set ? I mean always just make that new alarm everytime using caledar.set.. and then without repeating. Is there still something that I don't get.

Comment: I also have second problem. If I close application Alarms won't shows anymore. 

That was my first reason to use foreground-service. 

Just can't get that alarm system works using just broadcastreceiver and alarms.

Comment: @wiltson alarm purpose is to trigger either app is in background or foreground. 

It should work. mines do.

Make sure you have declare the receiver in manifest.  

        <receiver android:name="com.package.YourOnReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ifAny" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: @Wiltson did you get any solution to this ? I am getting same issue - not able get notifications when app is closed.

Comment: This is a bad example, first of all it's wrong, and second the code is very incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating alarm -- because you want notification every morning.

Alarm work efficiently just make sure you are passing the Time in Milliseconds properly. It works on background as well.